# Generating Random values for primary key in MySql

Tags: mysql, uuid

Is it sufficient to use UUID for generating random values in a column with Unique constraint?

Or should we *append* something like current timestamp to the UUID.

Or is there a better way to generate random yet unique values for a sql Column.

Comment: UUID suffices in 99.9999% of all use cases. (or even more 9s)

Comment: _"...for primary key..."_ isn't autoincrement enough?

Comment: I want them to be random. A user should not be able to guess other users Id.

Comment: but why is that?

Comment: A user will enter some id and then i have to show the record corresponding to that id. If they are auto increment, one can fake as other user by guessing ID.

Comment: So you are in the process of creating a perfect example of security by obscurity. Guessing an ID must no grant access to anything.

Comment: _"A user will enter some id..."_ so your users will have to memorize the UUID? o.O

Comment: A user is an api itself.

Answer (score 0):

Generating random numbers in any language is a misnomer. The numbers are pseudo random. Meaning not entirely 100% random.

Also take into the scenario of generating a random number in the range of 1-5. You might get duplicates generating the same number. Or if you generate more than 5 numbers you absolutely WILL have duplicates.

Time stamp tends to be a good UUID if the fields are only updated from one place. But then you also have to worry about things such as making sure it is in the correct format. Especially when changing between languages/technologies.

With user ID why not just auto increment a column with the values? Start the column somewhere and increment from there. I would leave a few numbers at the beginning of the list so that you have some empty ones early on if you need them for test/admin.